# How to access admin page - website like button

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am in the process of adding Like buttons to all of the product pages on a website.  I am using all of the proper open graph tags and an app_id and everything seems to be working fine.  I will be using a version of the button that does not give you the Admin or Insights links to choose from.  I am wondering if there is an easy way to access those pages without the links?

Even though I am listed as an admin of the App, I am not automatically listed as an admin of each of the product pages as they are created.  The only way I have been able to do it is to:

1. Add the default Like button code to another area of the page.
2. Click on the admin link then add myself as a page admin.
3. Delete the extra button on the page.
4. Access the admin area by going to facebook/pages.

This will be a pain as I add in hundreds of products! Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The admin page will appear in your news feed page, 1 or 2 days after you like & listed as admin of the website. If you accidentally delete it, the page will re-appear few days later if there is activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. Sadly your way of being admin of a page via an extra button didn't work for me.
I've found this related bug in facebook developers website : http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/160664854023586?browse=search_4e946433c82379f78564182

Comment: Clemi, did the page you were trying to gain admin access to already have likes from someone sharing the url before  you added the like button?  That is the only way I have found the tedious workaround listed above wont work.